# Derby driver not found in Java 9 module

Tags: java, database-connection, derby, java-9

I'm trying to get a Java 9 module to connect to the inbuilt Derby database (embed mode). My module has a dependency on `java.sql`, but I'm not sure where to put the Derby driver.

Here's my `module-info.java`:

```
module mymodule {
    requires java.sql;
}
```

Here's the `Main.java` code in the module that fails to execute:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

...
    Connection conn;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:mysampledb");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        s.executeUpdate("create table testtable (" +
            "id VARCHAR(256), " +
            "value VARCHAR(256)) ");
        s.close();

    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error connecting " + e);
    }
}
```

This compiles fine, but does not execute.

```
java -cp derbyjars --module-path out -m mymodule/foo.Main

Error connecting java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:mysampledb
```

How do I add the DB drivers? Is that using the -cp option? I have placed all the derby jars in the folder `derbyjars` and I'm passing that to the `-cp` option. Is there another way to make the module *see* the drivers?

Comment: I don't know how to solve that particular problem but here's something that might help: The `java.sql` module locates `java.sql.Driver` implementations using [services](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#services) (check by running `java --list-modules java.sql`). If the derbyjar were a module, it would declare that it provides a `Driver` implementation and the SQL module would pick it up. I have no clue how to achieve that without a module. You might be required to handcraft your own module descriptor and patch the JAR.

Comment: Is `derbyjars` a shorthand in your question? Or is it, e.g., the fully-qualified pathname to `derbyrun.jar`? It's best to be as precise and exact as you can be in your question, details matter. As far as I know, specifying a **folder** in the `-cp` argument does not mean that all the jars in that folder are added to the `CLASSPATH`; you must specify the jar file names explicitly. Only individual `.class` files are picked up from underneath a folder.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Thank you! You highlighted what I was missing. I was pointing the `-cp` parameter to a folder. I had to replace it with the individual jar files, and that worked! And to answer your question, yes, like I mentioned,  `derbyjars` is the name of the folder where I placed my jars.

Comment: @Nicolai Would that be the recommended way of adding database drivers into a Java 9 application? It works with the classpath option now, but it feels *wrong* because ideally a classpath should have no place in a Java 9 app. Thoughts? Also, how would I *patch* a jar into a module? Isn't it this same problem all over again with *that* module?

Comment: D'oh, stupid class path - I should've seen that. You can make it use all JARs in a folder wihth `derbyjars/*`. In the long run, yes, declaring a service implementation should be the way to go but I'm sure it will take a while to get there. Patching sucks and should be the absolute last resort.

Answer (score 3):

The `-cp` parameter takes in the individual jar names. Not the name of the folder containing the jars. (Thanks @BryanPendleton).

I changed my command to the one below, and it worked:

```
java -cp "derbyjars/*" --module-path out -m mymodule/foo.Main
```