# Java 9 JDBC setup

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pg-jdbc

### The problem

I'm currently working with Java 9 and its module system and want to connect to my PostgreSQL database via JDBC.

The problem is that I could not find any information on its setup with Java 9 and it's module system but only for Java 8 and older.

### The question

How can I properly setup JDBC and its driver using the java module system?

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: You are making this way too difficult. A JDBC driver is a jar. Do jar stuff.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As far as I know, for a library without any module description a new module based on the jar file name will be created. Thus I tried to put `requires postgresql-42.2.8` in my module-info.jar but this did not work.

Comment: @ShadowDragon Recent version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver declare `Automatic-Module-Name: org.postgresql.jdbc` in their manifest, so the module name is `org.postgresql.jdbc`. However, your own module doesn't need to require the PostgreSQL JDBC driver, as `DriverManager` (in module `java.sql`) loads the driver through the service loader mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar must be on the classpath *at runtime*. For compilation you do not need the jar.

If the Postgresql driver is modularized already it would would work with the `uses/provides` mechanism for runtime:

The java JRE:

```
module java.sql {
   uses java.sql.Driver;
   exports java.sql;
}
```

The driver then should have something like this in module-info:

```
module org.postgresql {
   requires java.sql;
   provides java.sql.Driver with org.postgresql.Driver;
}
```

And the normal ServiceLoader would discover the driver automatically.

`Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` generally is not needed, just in some JavaEE applications where there is some class loader juggling.

Comment: Looking at the documentation: It's not yet modularized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969977/derby-driver-not-found-in-java-9-module had a similar problem and there it was just the wrong classpath. Indeed 4.2, java 8, no module-info.class.

Comment: Without a module-info.class, I think it should work as well if the driver is on the module-path (not the class-path).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks, I thought that jars on the _classpath_ were considered "unnamed" modules. Are you sure? (I lack the experience.)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hm, interesting. We learned that Java will generate a module based on the jar files name for every jar without a module description (unnamed module).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure anymore. I experimented with modules a while ago and I thought that was sufficient, but I'll need to try again to be sure. You might be right that having it on the class-path would work as well.

Comment: @ShadowDragon The unnamed module is something else than generated module names.

Comment: Automatic Modules (like the PostgreSQL driver) should also work on the module-path.

Comment: Note that automatic modules (like the PostgreSQL driver 42.4.1) will work on the module-path when run with the `java` command, but not with a module linking tool like jlink (which requires all linked modules to not be automatic modules).

Comment: Tracking info for the [feature request to define a module-info for the postgres JDBC jar](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1979).